# Automatically copy contents from "Search Folders" subfolder

Tags: vba, outlook

[Copy contents of folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oY3x1.png)

Will there be any method to copy the emails inside of a "Search Folders" subfolder to another subfolder created under the main folder of my email address automatically?. (eg. as seen from the image above from step 1 to step 2?)

Answer (score 0):

A Search Folder is functionally similar to regular folders.  To access them you can get them from Explorer.CurrentFolder, via NameSpace.GetFolderFromID (if you know the ID), or you can enumerate them via [Store.GetSearchFolders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.getsearchfolders). Then access the Folder.Items collection to get at the content.